# How to remove £ symbol from nested array and convert string to integer

Tags: regex, typescript, str-replace, ionic4

I've got a nested array of prices that are a string and I want to remove the `£` symbols and convert the string into an integer. I need to strip the `£` signs and also convert to a integer so I can use the values in a `chart.js` line graph.

I've been trying to use regex replace to remove the `£` sign but I don't think I can get it working because the strings are in a nested array. I can't seem to find anything on the net about replacing characters in a nested array. I haven't even tried converting the string to an integer yet, but wondering if it could all be handled in one go in someway?

this is my nested array called linedata

```
var linedata = [["£14.99,£14.99,£14.99"],["£34.99,£34.99,£34.99"]]
```

this is the code I've been playing around with

```
var re = /£/g; 
var newlinedata = linedata.replace(re, "");
```

Its not returning anything in chrome console and the ionic CLI is kicking out this error

> ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts(66,26): error TS2339: Property
>   'replace' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This expression might help you to replace that:

```
£([0-9.]+,?)
```

The key is to add everything you like to keep in the capturing group `()` and the pound symbol outside of the group, then simply replace it with `$1`.

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1dLGad/1/).

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /£([0-9.]+,?)/gm;
const str = `£14.99,£14.99,£14.99
£34.99,£34.99,£34.99`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture in a group matching a digit with an optional decimal part after matching the `£`

```
£(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

- `£` Match literally
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional part to match a dot and 1+ digits
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lbBbjI/1)

You should use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on a string instead of an array.

To turn the nested array with the strings into arrays of numbers, you could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and in the replacement refer to the capturing group using `$1` which contains your value.

For example:

```js
var linedata = [
  ["£14.99,£14.99,£14.99"],
  ["£34.99,£34.99,£34.99"]
].map(ary =>
  ary[0].split(',')
  .map(v => Number(v.replace(/£(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g, "$1")))
);

console.log(linedata);
```

Or if you want to keep multiple nested arrays, you could use another map.

```js
var linedata = [
  ["£14.99,£14.99,£14.99"],
  ["£34.99,£34.99,£34.99", "£34.99,£34.99,£34.99"]
].map(ary => ary
  .map(s => s.split(',')
    .map(v => Number(v.replace(/£(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/g, "$1")))
  )
);

console.log(linedata);
```